# JAVA - Jpeg Images To Movie

Tags: java, image, jpeg, media

I am using the JpegImagesToMovie.java  to convert images to a .AVI file.
[Here](https://code.google.com/p/mediacomp-jes/source/browse/jes/Sources/JpegImagesToMovie.java?r=75)

I create object by this code:

```
Images2Video video = new Images2Video();

video.createMediaLocator("C:\\Users....");
Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();

File f = new File("C:\\Users\....");

FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
        if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

File[] fileList = f.listFiles(textFilter);

for( int i=0; i < fileList.length; i++){
    vec.add(fileList[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
MediaLocator outML = Images2Video.createMediaLocator("Video2.AVI");


video.doItAVI(325, 359, 40,vec, outML);
```

And I got this error:

> - create processor for the image datasource ...
>     Failed to build a graph for the given custom options.
>     Failed to realize: com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@43665c86
>     Cannot build a flow graph with the customized options:
>     Unable to transcode format: JPEG, 325x359, FrameRate=40.0
>       to: CVID
>       outputting to: video.x_msvideo
>     Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.ProcessEngine@43665c86
>     Failed to realize the processor.

If I used "doItMov" method it's work perfect.